# obj file in three.js gets an error on render

Tags: three.js

Using current version of three.js - Win 7 64bit - nvidia high end card, chrome 42, gets the error

> cannot read property x of undefined

- looks like wb is null in the minified code

main.html, obj and texture file can be obtained here:
http://96.56.225.196:8090/

Comment: can you link with the non-minified version?

Comment: @gaitat https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6463#issuecomment-96907445